# SELECT in FORM clause for view creation

Tags: mysql, view

I have this query I need to make a view with:

```
CREATE VIEW view_user_data AS
SELECT 
    u.uid AS uid, 
    u.name AS name,     
    (coalesce(value1, 0) + coalesce(value2, 0)) AS total_value, 
    (
        SELECT 
            value 
        FROM table3 
        WHERE value > total_value 
        LIMIT 1
    ) - 1 AS value,
FROM users AS u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            a.id AS id, 
            ROUND(SUM(a.value * a.multiplier),0) AS value1 
        FROM table1 AS a 
        GROUP BY a.uid
    ) join1 ON u.uid = join1.uid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            b.id AS id,
            ROUND(SUM(b.value * b.multiplier),0) AS value2 
        FROM table2 AS b 
        GROUP BY b.uid
    ) join2 ON u.uid = join2.uid 
ORDER BY uid
```

When I try to though I get this message:

```
#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
```

There is no SELECT in any of my FROM clauses? What does that mean? Or is select in JOINS not supported as well?

The question is - is there a way I could make this view possible?

Comment: Could you provide the queries to create the underlying tables? In this way it would be easier to debug

Comment: in your left outer join clause you have subselect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid subselect creating the necessary subselect as views

```
  CREATE VIEW join1 AS 
    SELECT 
      a.id AS id, 
      ROUND(SUM(a.value * a.multiplier),0) AS value1 
    FROM table1 AS a 
    GROUP BY a.uid
  ;


  CREATE VIEW join2 AS 
    SELECT 
        b.id AS id,
        ROUND(SUM(b.value * b.multiplier),0) AS value2 
    FROM table2 AS b 
    GROUP BY b.uid
  ; 

  CREATE VIEW view_value AS 
    SELECT 
        value 
    FROM table3 
    WHERE value > total_value 
    LIMIT 1 
  ;


  CREATE VIEW view_user_data AS
  SELECT 
      u.uid AS uid, 
      u.name AS name,     
      (coalesce(value1, 0) + coalesce(value2, 0)) AS total_value, 
      view_value.value -1 as value,
  FROM users AS u
  CROSS JOIN  view_value 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN join1 ON u.uid = join1.uid 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN join2 ON u.uid = join2.uid 
  ORDER BY uid
```

Comment: Got it. This works perfect. So JOIN clause is basically a FROM clause (at least according to the error message). Thanks

Comment: @T.Maxx   .. correct  .. FROM and JOIN using subselect have similar behaviour   ..